# Suggestions on how to view an (anti) self folded triangle.

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Consider a triangle. Now chose two edges of this triangle and glue them together by the following orientation.

.----->-----.------>-----.

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**|

(Where the line underneath is meant to join the two vertices to form the rest of the triangle.)

My question is what does this look like. Any good tips on how to visualise this?

Comment: It feels like it's a figure of 8. Labelling your vertices A, B, C, we have that A, B and C are identified, and AB and BC are identified, but AC is still intact. Can anybody else with a stronger geometric intuition confirm?

Comment: By figure of eight do you mean mobius strip?

Comment: Yes. Consider .---->----.----<----.

This will just be a cone-esque shape. But those are the only two ways.

Comment: Alex, I have given the two possible glueings above.(One in my question, the other in the comments). Do you just not understand my notation.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of the triangle as a wire frame, not as a filled-out 2d shape. My above reasoning should still apply for the boundary (if it's correct), but I need to think some more about what happens to the interior.

Comment: Josh, I have actually made a physical glueing. I.e this can be embedded in 3-space.

Comment: Wow, I was pretty certain that it couldn't be embedded in space. Can you describe how it looks? Is it the "cone much like the layman's dunce cap" described on the wiki page linked to by user63654?

Comment: It turns out to be the Mobius strip! The glued side makes up a loop around the Mobius strip, and the unglued side is the boundary of the strip.

Comment: Nice work. More evidence of how intuition-defying these things can be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It turns out that this is in fact just the Mobius strip. The unglued side corresponds to the boundary of the Mobius strip, and the glued side corresponds to a closed curve on the strip that meets at some point on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If I am looking at this correctly then try this: the Mobius band is constructed by taking a square and identifying opposite sides via a twist. What you have is similar but now we must identify the single edge that's left after the identification. What we have constructed is in fact the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: If this is the case, then it is extremely helpful. Could you justify your answer please.

Comment: Well my answer is conditional on whether the left and right points are identified or are simple connected by an edge. If the former than it is $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: The vertices all collapse to one. Does this answer you question?

Comment: Oh I see, in that case it is certainly not $\mathbb{R}P^2$ or even a closed manifold (it has boundary). Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology))

Comment: What glueing were you thinking of that gave the projective 2 -space?